# Identify Shared mailbox name

Tags: vba, outlook

I have two mailboxes and I want a `message box` to identify the mailbox every time I use the `Reply Action`.

```
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents AVDEMAL As Outlook.Folder
Dim avdEMAILmoved As Outlook.Folder
Dim avdEMAILolns As Outlook.NameSpace

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set avdolns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set AVDAVDEMAIL = avdAVDEMAILolns.Folders("AVDAVDEMAIL").Folders("Inbox")
end sub

Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
If Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") = "AVDAVDEMAIL" Then
    MsgBox " hello , You are using AVD-EMAIL"
end if
end sub
```

When I run the code, it has no error but the message box didn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got it.

For other's reference, here's the solution. Just add the  code below.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox (oItem.Parent.store)
```

It works! :)

Comment: Are you sure this works?  `oItem.Parent.store` returns a `Store` object.  I woul expect you to need: `oItem.Parent.Store.Name`.

Comment: Yes, it is. I just finish my code with this. :) If you will add the .name, it will only show the main mailbox and it will not work on sharedmail box

Comment: I can only assume that `.Name` is the default property for `Store` which explains why you can omit it.  I do not understand why it does not work for a shared mailbox.  I am retired and no longer have access to shared mailboxes but, when I did, code that worked for private mailboxes also worked for shared.  It works which is the main thing; why is less important.